# toggle doesn't work in react, no error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My intention is to show the input field when the edit is pressed but with below code it doesn't work, I couldn't find out what is the problem, no error in the console.

http://jsbin.com/yezediloke/1/edit?js,console,output

```
class TodoItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.isEditing = false;
    this.onClickEdit = this.onClickEdit.bind(this);
  }
  onClickEdit(){
    this.setState({isEditing: !this.isEditing});
  }
  render(){
    return(

      <li>
        <span>{this.props.item}</span>
      {this.isEditing ? '<span><input type="text" /></span>' :''}
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<button onClick={this.onClickEdit}>Edit</button>
      <button>Save</button>
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: first of all, remove the `''` from '<span><input type="text" /></span>'

Comment: @A.Lau after that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 Problems:

1: You didn't set the initial state in constructor:

```
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.isEditing = false;
    this.onClickEdit = this.onClickEdit.bind(this);
    this.state = { isEditing: false };
  }
```

2 and 3: Span does not need `''` and `this.isEditing` should be `this.state.isEditing`

```
 render(){
    return(

      <li>
        <span>{this.props.item}</span>
/*Look here>>>*/ {this.state.isEditing ? <span><input type="text" /></span> :''}
      &nbsp;&nbsp;<button onClick={this.onClickEdit}>Edit</button>
      <button>Save</button>
      </li>
    )
  }
```

4: `this.isEditing` should be `this.state.isEditing` in onClickEdit

```
onClickEdit(){
    this.setState({isEditing: !this.state.isEditing});
  }
```

This works: http://jsbin.com/ganimopalo/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: `this.isEditing = false` is not state?

Comment: That is not in the state, that is just in the class. `this.state` is the state. Hence, `this.state.isEditing` is where the `isEditing` you want to be looking at

Comment: http://jsbin.com/cogopuvoke/1/edit?js,console,output can you take a look? doesn't work.

Comment: Because you're still using `this.isEditing` in the `render` part

Comment: A. Lau, why this save handler has error? http://jsbin.com/cogopuvoke/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: I just told you, you're still using `this.isEditing` instead of `this.state.isEditing` >WRONG>>>>> `{this.isEditing ? <span><input type="text" /></span> :''}`

Comment: check the fiddle again, I've solved the editing part

Comment: post new save link, because that one is the old one. And i'm going to sleep soon.

Comment: I'm still seeing a `this.isEditing` in your `render`. Look at my answer (2 and 3) and match it against yours.

Comment: try this link http://jsbin.com/gocuhedehe/1/edit sorry jsbin is strange.

Comment: you don't even have  `onSaveEdit()` function

Comment: I'm going to bed. If the answer has helped you, please mark it as answer so others may find it useful. If you have anymore questions, please look and see if you've actually set everything up correctly. And if you think so, then ask another question.

Comment: Jenny I recommend you move {this.state.isEditing ? <span><input type="text" /></span> :''} into a function  instead this will make it easier to maintain and read